# Determine time complexity for unpredictive non-linear iterative algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I don't know whether I used the **unpredictive** word correctly or not. But here's the problem:

I have a rectangular piece of paper of length a and breadth b. I will keep cutting the squares from it, of side equal to min(a,b) until the last square is of unit length. Determine the number of squares I can cut.

[image]

Here's my algorithm :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long a,b,temp,small,large,res;
    cin >> a >> b;
    res = 0;

    small = min(a,b);
    large = a + b - small;

    while(small > 0 && small != large)
    {
        res = res + large/small;
        temp = large % small;
        large = small;
        small = temp;
    }

    cout << res;
    return 0;
}
```

I am confused how to calculate time complexity in this case, as max(a,b) decreases to 1, in non-even fashion, depending upon the initial values of a and b. The best case would definitely be when, either or both of them is 1 already. The worst case would be, I guess, when both are prime. Please help me to analyze the time complexity.

Comment: Start with what represents the size of the problem.

Comment: The *best* case is when you start with a square (a=b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This algorithm is very similar to the Euclidean algorithm for computing the greatest common divisor. Recall that that algorithm works by:

- Start with two numbers `a, b`, assume without loss than `a >= b`. If `a == b` then stop.
- In the next round, the two numbers are `b` and `a % b` instead.

Now consider your algorithm. It's the same, except it's `a - b` instead. But this will actually do the same thing if `a < 2 * b`. And if `a < k * b`, then in the next round it changes only by a multiple of `b`, so after at most `k` rounds, it will converge to `a % b`. So this is just a slower version of the Euclidean algorithm.

The time complexity of the Euclidean algorithm is quite fast -- since it's repeated division, the number of rounds is not more than the number of digits.

Edit: To expand on last part:
To analyze the time complexity, a first question is, how many rounds does it take.

An easy way to start is, if `a` and `b` have `n` and `m` digits in their (binary) description, then there can't be more than `n + m` rounds. Because, as long as `b` is at least two in a given round, we will be dividing one of the numbers by two in that round, so the result will have one less digit. If `b` is one, then this is the last round.

A second question is, how much time does it take to do a single round.

If you are satisfied with "the running time is at most polynomial in the number of digits", then this is now clear, since you can easily do division in polynomial in the number of digits.

I'm not actually sure what the tightest analysis possible is. You might be able to do some kind of win-win analysis to improve on this, I'm almost sure this has been studied but I don't know a reference, sorry.

Comment: Good catch, it made me think of Euclide's gcd too.

Comment: @Chris : Oh yes... Its the Euclidean GCD only. In fact its the same copy. How come its slower version? I didn't get this one . Because in my view Euclidean also swaps the same way, `if(b == 0) return a; return gcd(b,a%b)`

Comment: Oh, I read your description and not your code. Sorry. I guess it's exactly the same if you are doing `a % b` and not `a - b`. I guess the problem statement is `a - b` but you do `a % b` as optimization, so you are doing it the fast way.

Comment: @ChrisBeck : Thanks for the help. It didn't hit me at all... I am going to check the proof of time complexity of Eucliden gcd now. Last time when I saw the same, it almost went over my head ;) I hope this time I will catch it, because I implemented Euclidean GCD unknowingly ;)